# Cuda Single Thread Debug

Tags: cuda

I'm currently trying to debug CUDA C++ code with Nsight. What I'm really after is to make things faster when debugging CUDA C++ Code. For this purpose, I need to reduce the debugging problem to only single thread. So now, I'm asking how is it possible to debug only single thread in CUDA if possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can freeze the other threads in Nsight.

1. Open "Nsight -> Windows -> Cuda Info" when on bp is hit.
2. Switch to "Warps" tab and select which warp you want to freeze via context menu.
3. Switch to "Lanes" tab and select which thread you want to freeze in current warp.